# How to write readHTMLTable() result to file

Tags: r, web-scraping

This is my code but I want to format the data put it down in a web page.

```
library(XML)
noria = readHTMLTable("http://www.fundacionguanajuato.com/CGI-BIN/Clima/Actual.php?Est=noria")
raws.data <- readLines(noria, warn = "F")

str(noria)
noria
```

I get the result but I can't see the correct format when I export it to .csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readHTMLTable` command returns a list of tables.  See pages 69-71 of [the Package:XML documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/XML.pdf).

If you want to write a particular table to a `CSV` file, you have to specify which one in your `noria` list variable.  For example:

```
table8 <- noria[[8]]
write.csv(table8, "noria_table8.csv")
```

Comment: @RichardScrivens: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Richard, how do you know it is table8?  I copied that link into my browser, hit F12 to see the HTML, and I did a search for 'table8' and 'noria'.  I didn't find either.  I looked in the HTML, body, and table; I didn't find 'noria' or 'table8'.
Thanks.

Comment: @ryguy72 The page may have changed. Table 8 was used as an example of the syntax. You should specify whichever table is appropriate for your task.